# Erro numa Trigger envolvendo Linked Server

Tags: sql, oracle

Criei uma Trigger que busca dados de uma tabela do SQL Server e escreve ou atualiza dados de outra tabela no Oracle caso haja alteração. Tudo isso via LinkedServer. Mas ao executá-la gera o seguinte erro:

> O provedor do OLE DB "OraOLEDB.Oracle" para o servidor vinculado "INTERFTRIMERP" retornou a mensagem "New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator. ".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure InserePedidoQtdProgAlterada, Line 39
>   A operação não pôde ser realizada porque o provedor do OLE DB "OraOLEDB.Oracle" para o servidor vinculado "INTERFTRIMERP" não pôde iniciar uma transação distribuída.

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Com tabelas somente do SQL Server funciona normalmente, agora via linked server para o Oracle, gera esse erro.

Comment: Marcio, não ficou claro uma coisa: a trigger é disparada de uma tabela no SQL Server ou no Oracle? Se possível fornecer as versões do banco

Comment: Márcio, você precisa garantir que o driver do Oracle usado na configuração do LinkedServer suporta transações distribuídas. O problema provavelmente é a transação que há no seu código do SQL. Isso é mesmo necessário? Uma alternativa "somente-leitura" seria ler dados do Oracle antes e depois iniciar a transação de alteração no SQL Server.

Comment: @gmSantos, a trigger é disparada quando é inserido ou alterado dados de uma tabela no SQLServer 2012.

Comment: @utluiz, como faço para verificar se o drive utilizado suporta transações distribuidas?

Comment: @MárcioMorando encontrei um KB da Microsoft que descreve o erro que você está passando. Verifique se pode te ajudar: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280106/pt-br

Comment: @MárcioMorando Então, uma vez eu precisei fazer isso, mas já faz tempo e foi em outra empresa. Não tenho como consultar o material que deixei lá. Pelo que me lembro o Oracle tem mais de um tipo de Driver. Há o cliente simples e o mais completo, com suporte a XA (transações distribuídas). Note no link que o `gmsantos` passou há alguma coisa lá com `xa.dll`. Deve ser isso que está faltando. Infelizmente a configuração dessas coisas depende muito também da versão do Oracle que você está usando e também varia se for 32 ou 64 bits. Cuidado com essas diferenças, não misture SQL Server 34 com DLL 64.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.